# Flutter Infinite Scroll type null is not a subtype of string in type cast

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, scroll

I am trying to make an infinite news widget, so I made this test widget (you can call this by putting 'NewsFeed' as a child in your build function) but it is erroring with the error '_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)' and I don't know why. Thanks!

EDIT: I added a future.delayed but I don't think it is ever being called because I didn't have to wait for 5 minutes.

Here is my code for more information:

```
class NewsFeed extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  GetNews createState() => GetNews();
}

class GetNews extends State<NewsFeed> {
  var _posts;

  bool _hasNextPage = true;
  bool _isFirstLoadRunning = false;
  bool _isLoadMoreRunning = false;

  void _loadMore() async {
    if (_hasNextPage == true &&
        _isLoadMoreRunning == false &&
        _controller.position.extentAfter < 300) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoadMoreRunning = true; // Display a progress indicator at the bottom
      }); // Increase _page by 1

      try {
        var res = [
          {
            'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
            'by': 'someone',
            'intro-text':
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
            'image':
                'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
          },
          {
            'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
            'by': 'someone',
            'intro-text':
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
            'image':
                'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
          }
        ];
        if (res.isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
            _posts.addAll(res);
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _hasNextPage = false;
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        print('Something went wrong!');
      }

      setState(() {
        _isLoadMoreRunning = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void start() {
    _posts = [
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': 'someone',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
        'image':
            'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': 'someone',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
        'image':
            'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
      }
    ];
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 300));

    setState(() {
      _isFirstLoadRunning = false;
    });
  }

  late ScrollController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isFirstLoadRunning = true;
    start();
    _controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_loadMore);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isFirstLoadRunning
        ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _posts.length,
                  controller: _controller,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) => Card(
                    margin:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 10),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(_posts[index]['title'] as String),
                      subtitle: Text(_posts[index]['body'] as String),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (_isLoadMoreRunning == true)
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 40),
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ),
              if (_hasNextPage == false)
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 40),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('You have fetched all of the content'),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you posts there is no value with key 'body'
Maybe try this

```
subtitle: Text((_posts[index]['body'] as String?)??""),
```

or maybe you are trying to display intro-text

```
 subtitle: Text((_posts[index]['intro-text'] as String)),
```